# Damage increased by light

Tags: destiny

How much of an increase in damage does light do? In-game it says

> Light increases your level, increasing the damage your abilities deal against higher-level enemies

but I would like to know the specific increase.

Comment: [related, but not dupe](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/183792/how-is-damage-calculated)

Comment: I really need to sit down and spreadsheet this, but it's hard for me to get a feeling for it since higher level missions also make the enemies more aggressive and give other changes to the rules. Plus trying to take on enemies above your level at the high end is not exactly fun for me. Maybe this will be my weekend project.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First off, leveling up will not increase your gun's damage unless you're already experiencing downscaling due to being underlevelled, but it **does** increase ability damage (as the description says). I just did some testing to see how level affects the damage of your abilities (which Destiny takes to mean super, grenade and melee skill). I tested with my Gunslinger, using throwing knife and Golden Gun against level 20 Fallen Shanks (by going to a level 20 version of story mission).

This level was chosen because it's not above any of the levels I'll test (unlike 24) and still are not far enough down that you'll get level scaling from being too high (refer to note about scaling at the end).

The results are here, with level given as Level(Light amount) as given by the number next to the progress bar when hovering over light level:

```
  LvL  | Melee | Super
-------+-------+-------
 27(96)|  615  | 2153
 27(89)|  590  | 2063
 25(71)|  529  | 1849
 23(49)|  462  | 1617
```

So as you can tell, ability damage does scale with light level. One surprising aspect of this, which I only noticed because I equipped the wrong legendary armor (Queen's gear... you know how it is), is that it's not your **level** that determines damage, but your total amount of light. This means that every time you apply a defense upgrade (which gives you a little bit of extra light), your abilities power up slightly too. Neat!

This increase seems to be linear, and with my skills (throwing knife and golden gun) the increase per unit of light is 3.2 damage for melee and 11.2 for super.

In addition, I did a minor test to see if level difference has any effect on damage, by going to the 24 version of the same mission, and throwing some knives around. Results:

```
  LvL  | Dmg 
-------+-----
 27(96)| 615 
 27(89)| 590 
 25(71)| 529 
 23(49)| 315
```

Here you can see that the only difference is that level scaling was applied when we were underleveled. As for how damage scaling in relation to level differences works, I'll copy paste my comment on another answer in this question here:

> Damage scaling occurs if the enemy is above your level (the drop off is more like 30% per level, ending up with "Immune" at 4 levels difference, when enemies become ??s), or the enemy is more than 9 level below your weapon's "internal level", when you start losing about 5% damage per level. "Internal level" seems to be defined as the weapon's level requirement until for whites and greens, but has an added bonus for blues and legendaries. My purple "requires 20" acts like it's level 27

In addition, I'll note that for the purposes of ability damage, it counts as having the same "internal level" as you.

Comment: and proof of all this info?

Comment: The data in the post is not enough for you? I mean, I can't provide video of the data (360, no capture card), but the "proof" is right there. As for the bit about level scaling: yes, I do have data, but not in a form that's fit for putting here, and it was only tangential to the question at hand, so I don't want to clutter the answer up.

Comment: @Dupree3 I've seen the request for hard proof on a couple of other Destiny questions as well, and if this is a requirement it's better to just flag the questions as opinion-based and close them. Unless Bungie posts actual hard data from the game, observations are all we will get. In other words, the above is about as much proof as we can muster for these things. Yes, videos and screenshots would be even better but not all platforms can do that easily. Feel free to do a video capture and some experimentation on your own and post the results though.

Answer (score 0):

What that means is that light increases your level. Full stop.

Having a higher level, will increase your damage to enemies. Full stop.

---

For every level you are under from your enemy your damage takes a percentage decrease (*about 10%*) - for every level over, your damage increases (*about 6%*).

Comment: Your damage decreases if you are too high of a level. signified by gray damage numbers.

Comment: Your damage doesn't decrease as you level up, against lower level mobs. Instead it is "stuck at the mobs level", and thus you're not doing the same amount of damage you would if you were attacking a mob your own level.

Comment: To clarify this, it seems to the player like the damage decreases (and in game says decreases) because it's not doing the full potential damage of the weapon. Both of the above comments are exactly correct, just one is from the enemy's frame of reference and the other is from the player's frame of reference.

Comment: Damage scaling occurs if the enemy is above your level (the drop off is more like 30% per level, ending up with "Immune" at 4 levels difference, when enemies become ??s), or the enemy is more than 9 level below your weapon's "internal level", when you start losing about 5% damage per level. "Internal level" seems to be defined as the weapon's level requirement until for whites and greens, but has an added bonus for blues and legendaries. My purple "requires 20" acts like it's level 27.

Answer (score -2):

Here ya go. Video proof that his info is correct.

Comment: Hi @MarteinnOrnOskarsson, welcome to Gaming.SE - Just a note: We frown upon link-only answer. Perhaps you could explain what the video is trying to proof, and by the way: **He's looking for the equation that determines the damage.**