# Destiny damage behaviours

Tags: destiny

I'm actually making a damage simulator for destiny, and it's actually coming out to be pretty precise (it has a range of +-5% damage accuracy).

I've gathered many informations from the whole destiny community, from google and so on, but I'm actually trying to understand some things that are actually quite unclear to me.

First of all, I've pretty well understood that there are several damage multipliers and that, generically, those damage multipliers are actually static.

I've already checked this topic: [How is damage calculated?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/183792/how-is-damage-calculated)

But I currently didn't find some more informations I need.

From what I've read in the web, sniper rifles, since october 14th have a **2.5** damage multiplier, therefore a sniper rifle with 132 attack and 33% impact should be dealing **326.7** for headshots to mobs of the same level as the player (and It actually works, tested it).

What is bothering me, though, is WHY sometimes headshots on weaker enemies deals about 1000-2000-3000 damage. Is there any bonus for being higher than an enemy target?

A clear example of what I mean is this:

If you consider this video ->

at 14 seconds the ice breaker sniper rifle shot deals **2851** damage to the knight (and same applies to acolytes, therefore it shouldn't be related by any mean to the shield bonus thing).

Since the ice breaker at its maximum stats should be having an impact of 28 and a damage of 300, how on earth is it dealing 2851? the sniper rifle precise damage multiplier is 2.5, so how is it dealing that much damage? I'm not really finding any explanation to such a thing, moreover, the rest of my simulations seems to be very accurate, but sniper rifles seems to be reacting very differently regardless their impact and other statistics.

Has anyone a clearer idea of how it actually works?

Thanks,

Briosheje

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is damage calculated?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/183792/how-is-damage-calculated)

Comment: Unfortunately, this is one of those things that is part of the question you linked.  I'd recommend adding a comment requesting this specific information.

Comment: Did you read the question or completely skipped it? I precised that the informations I need are NOT in the link you put there that, by the way, I've added in my question above since the beginning. The question is completely different from the other one, here I'm asking specifically if sniper rifles have a different behaviour, not how the damage of everything is calculated.

Comment: Nope, I read the question.  And answers to the one you linked *should* answer your aspect as well.  That's why I said you should add a comment requesting the information you're specifically looking for.

Comment: I've already read the question there, and it currently doesnt' answer. The data provided by the answer is related to every kind of primary weapons and some specials, but NOT sniper rifles. Again, this is not a duplicate, read before considering a question a duplicate.

Comment: The question asks, "How is damage calculated?".  What you are asking is a small portion of that calculation, which is what the whole point of that question is.  That's why I believe it's a dupe, and why I think you should be commenting.

Comment: Why should I be commenting if the matter is not as specific as this? Answer to my question first: they are literally talking about other things there, they need to find how the damage is calculated, not how sniper rifles damage varies according to we don't know really what. To me, it is not the same. It's like asking how an apple tastes and how an apple is composed inside, I don't think it's actually the same.

Comment: I've noticed just through playing that the icebreaker and hawkmoon seem to do way more damage than any legendary.  Perhaps exotics have some sort of different multiplier? Or have you experienced this with other sniper rifles (non exotic).  What do you calculate the icebreaker should do for a headshot?  Perhaps if you check the ratio you can find another multiplier, and then test with patience and time.

Comment: @turbo: actually I've been testing around for quite a while and it actually seems that sniper rifles has a "bonus" of the 81%. Example: if you calculate the "base" damage of the ice breaker, it would be around 500 and something. Considering the amount shown in game, I've estimated that it seems that the 500 damage is about the 19% of the damage dealt. Therefore, by doing some proportions, I'm actually calculating the base damage and I'm considering it as the 19% of the entire damage, which seems to be working with the majority of the sniper rifles (it is not exatly precise, though).